# How do I make an image have padding while keeping the webkit-box-shadow?

Tags: css, webkit

I want to style all of the images on my website to have box-shadows and padding of 10px, so that text isn't smooshed up against them. However, when I assign any padding to "img" with CSS, the box-shadow is drawn at the edge of the padding, leaving a 10px blank space around the image.

```
#content img {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #282a2d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #282a2d;
    padding:10px
}
```

This particular image is floated left within the paragraph. here is an example of my problem -

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I do not want the padding. I just want the box-shadow, and then space, so that text doesn't mash up right next to the box-shadow. Turns out what I wanted was margin, not padding. Silly mistake.

Comment: Although, you can't post a picture, you can post a fiddle instead.

Comment: If you didn't wanted padding, you shouldn't mention that in your question.

Comment: I was confused as to what padding actually was, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `margin` in addition to `padding`

```
#content img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #282a2d;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;  
}
```

Comment: I actually don't want the padding, I was confused. I just added a simple `margin:10px;` which gave me what I wanted.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, Sorry for the misunderstanding caused by the OP, removed my comment and vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give the background of the same color

```
#content img {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #282a2d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #282a2d;
    background: #282a2d;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4UrPW/)

---

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in comment, OP seems to be OK without padding too. So, I will just complete my answer.

```
#content img {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #282a2d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #282a2d;
    margin:10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@zellio's answer didn't work for me, so I solved it by adding two elements.

```
<div class="with-padding>
<div class=with-shadow>
...
</div>
</div>

.with-padding {
padding = 10px;
}

.with-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #282a2d;
}
```